# iPhoto - Removing image files that weren't taken by a camera

Tags: photos.app, exif

I recently attempted to import my archive of 20000 photos into iPhoto - unfortunately I found out that some of the imported images were not photos but things I downloaded from the internet.

I would like to know how I can filter these images according to their Exif tags. I want to specify the cameras whose photos I want to keep - and the rest I want to delete. Is this possible using iPhoto / is there a script that will do this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What exif tags are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a smart album to divide your pictures into the ones you wish to keep & the ones to delete. There are several metadata fields you can use to create an album that divides your images - you should likely start with the Camera Model field.

So, to do this,

1. Select New Smart Album in iPhoto
2. Under Match the following condition, select Camera Model is (whatever camera you wish to retain).
3. If you have several cameras create more than one condition, and change the "Match all of the following conditions" to "Match any of the following conditions."

Depending on your setup, you can reverse this search - instead creating a Smart Album that contains just the images that weren't taken with any of your cameras, and then deleting the downloaded ones...